# Memory leak when rewriteing a 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to call a function that uses my 2d dynamic array to create another 2d dynamic array and then rewrite the value for my first array. So the code is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **bigger(int **A)
{
    int i;
    int **A2 = (int **)malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        A2[i] = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    return A2; 
    }

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int **A = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    A = bigger(A);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        free(A[i]);

    free(A);

    return 0;
}
```

If I check it with `valgrind --leak-check=yes` I get total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 240 bytes allocated. How can I solve this memory leak ?

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR**, you're not *re-writing*, you're *overwriting*.

The problem is in

```
 A = bigger(A);
```

inside `bigger()` function, you're allocating new memories and then, storing the same back into `A`, which makes you lose the pointer to previously allocated memories, thus rendering them *unreachable* and are not `free()`-d. Those causes the leak here.

You need to use [`realloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) for resizing already `malloc()`ed memory regions.

Otherwise, before you call `malloc()` again, inside the `bigger()`, you ought to `free()` the available memories.

Comment: But how do i solve the problem if i need another copy of the original array in my function, let's say A and A2, i do my tasks and then i return A2 ?